# How can I center a container when the screen space is taken over by other element?

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical sidebar navigation menu aligned to the left that has a width of 211px and height of 300px.  I then have a container that is 960px wide.  Since 211px of the screen width is being taken by the sidebar the container is overlapping with it when i center it using margin: 0 auto;

How can I center the container from the navigation menu rather than the general screen width with a solution where it will appear centered from the navigation menu across all browsers/platforms?

[image]

Comment: Wrap the container and give the inner container a `margin-left: 211ishpx`?

Comment: @RitabrataGautam Thanks.  Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

wrap the container with another div(ex. `.wrapper`).make the width of wrapper total view port width minus side bar width and then use `margin:0 auto` in container

EXAPLE:: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u7Nzh/)

Comment: Actually you are using percentage widths and heights.  I need it in pixels because on mobile and ipad the percentage widths don't work well with what I have right now.. I tried substituting with pixels but then the issue returns...